# Do we have some sort of a Triple collection in C#

Tags: c#, collections

I was thinking of keeping three pieces of information for each object of a list.
So I can create a class with three properties for those three pieces of information, and then create a Collection of that class type... But I was wondering in .NET 3.5 ( and not 4.0 ) have any thing built in for that? for example a dictionary...that one keep two pieces of information for each item, key and value...but I need three. Do we have anything built-in for that?

Comment: I suppose you could use `List<Tuple<A, B, C>>` but are you looking for specific semantics?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9163732/726127

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can create your own `Tuple<T1, T2, T3>`:

```
public class Tuple<T1, T2, T3> : IEquatable<Object>{
    public T1 Item1{
        get;
        set;
    }

    public T2 Item2{
        get;
        set;
    }

    public T3 Item3{
        get;
        set;
    }

    public Tuple(T1 Item1, T2 Item2, T3 Item3){
         this.Item1 = Item1;
         this.Item2 = Item2;
         this.Item3 = Item3;
    }

    public override bool Equals( object obj ) {
        if ( obj == null || (obj as Tuple<T1, T2, T3>) == null ) //if the object is null or the cast fails
            return false;
        else {
            Tuple<T1,T2,T3> tuple = ( Tuple<T1, T2, T3> ) obj;
            return Item1.Equals( tuple.Item1 ) && Item2.Equals(tuple.Item2) && Item3.Equals(tuple.Item3);
        }
    }

    public override int GetHashCode( ) {
        return Item1.GetHashCode( ) ^ Item2.GetHashCode() ^ Item3.GetHashCode();
    }

    public static bool operator == ( Tuple<T1, T2, T3> tuple1, Tuple<T1, T2, T3> tuple2 ) {
        return tuple1.Equals( tuple2 );
    }

    public static bool operator != ( Tuple<T1, T2, T3> tuple1, Tuple<T1, T2, T3> tuple2 ) {
        return !tuple1.Equals( tuple2 );
    }
}
```

Comment: Cools, just a minor edit to your code: Item2 and Item3 should be of types T2 and T3,  prob a copy paste error :)

Comment: I like this solution because as @ChaosPandion points out, it follows what is built into .NET 4.0.  When you upgrade you can remove this class altogether.

Comment: If you're intending to do equality comparisons with the tuple you really need to make it immutable and implement `Equals` and a suitable `GetHashCode`. The tuple as it is defined will give you unexpected results for comparisons.

Comment: @Enigmativity oh thanks, didn't know that.. I want it to keep a string and two of my own classes so like <String, OwlClass, OwlAnnotation> ... But no "comparison" I will do .. will it still be a problem? Then I am gonna have a ICollection of objects of this Tuple class.

Answer (score 14):

Create your own Triple class:

```
public class Triple<T,X,Y>
{
   public T t{get;set;}
   public X x{get;set;}
   public Y y{get;set;}
}
```

It's a clear approach and more manageable than directly using a dictionary, like: `Dictionary<Key, KeyValuePair<X,Y>>` and other approaches like this.

Comment: yes, looks like thats the only way to do it, Tuples are for .NET 4.0

Comment: I would actually follow the convention used in .NET 4 for tuples so you can easily swap them out if you so desire.

Comment: @ChaosPandion : thanks, what do you mean by "follow convention used in .NET 4 for tuples" ?

Comment: I think he means "syntax and semantics" rather than "convention".

Comment: @Saeed:Copy Pasted the Triple class, it gives me errors saying "Member with the same name is already declared.

Comment: @BDotA - I believe that it would be beneficial to implement a "Tuple" object in the same manner that it is implemented in .NET 4 so an upgrade means you can remove your version and simplify your libraries.

Comment: @ChaosPandion, Implementing whole tuple class is useless, but I'll update my answer with variation of your suggestion. Edit: Someone else did it, so I'll left this as this way.

Answer (score 3):

The solution of creating a generic tuple class similar to the one that's added in .Net 4 is explained in other answers, but I do feel it's important to state that it might be better to create a small class to semantically represent the data you're storing with meaningful properties.  A generic 3-tuple might work now, but you might want to expand on the functionality later.

Comment: You make an important point. Tuple is most appropriate when used internally within a module or a generally small project.

Comment: Exactly.  A great and natural time for Tuple<...> is when you're implementing an algorithm that's really abstract like a really obscure graph algorithm or math algorithm or something.

Answer (score 2):

If you were using .NET 4, you'd be looking for [`Tuple<T1,T2,T3>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). .NET 3.5 doesn't have a built-in type, but depending on your needs, you can do a `Dictionary<T1,Dictionary<T2,Dictionary<T3,bool>>>`

Answer (score 1):

Try `Dictionary<Key, Tuple<Object, Object>>` or, alternatively, `Dictionary<Key, YourClass>` where YourClass (which could be a struct, of course), holds the two required pieces of data.

Comment: Tuple isn't available in .NET 3.5.

Comment: @Kendall - You are technically correct but it is trivial to implement.

Comment: @KendallFrey: Edited for an alternative.